# timefold.ai partial pinning

Tags: java, optaplanner, timefold

I'm currently performing some tests with timefold.ai optimization java framework.

I have the following scenario: I have tasks that need to be executed on a specific time. However they are optional, they don't have to be scheduled. But if they are scheduled they have to start at a specific time.

Additionally there are other tasks (same type of tasks, so they are in the same collection) and representated by the same `PlanningEntity` that are completely flexibile, both in starting time and also whether they are scheduled at all.

Afaik regular pinning doesn't work as it pins the entire planning entity. My simplified setup looks something like this (Not including additional not relevant constraints).

```java
@PlanningEntity
public class Task {

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = ["myValueRangeProvider"], nullable = true)
    private BigDecimal start;
  
    @PlanningPin
    private boolean pinned;

}
```

```java
@PlanningSolution
class PlanningProblem {

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "myValueRangeProvider")
    private CountableValueRange<BigDecimal> possibleStarts;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Task> tasks;

}
```

Does someone have an idea how to nicely model it? Is there some way to partially pin variables? I also thought about having two planning variables, one `isScheduled` and another one `start` and somehow using a specific value range provider per entity, but I can only provide one per entity type I assume?

Thanks!

Comment: One idea I had just now is to introduce a new planning entity collection. One that is called `optionalFlexibleTask` and another one `optionalFixedTasks`.
This is not ideal because I have additional constraints that have to be considered for the union of those two, but I guess I can use `concat` in the contraint provider. Will this have a big performance impact? The documentation says that introducing new planning entities makes the search space much larger, but I would assume that this is not the case here?

Comment: Also just introducing a hard constraint that checks for those entities whether the start is equals to a specific fixed value is not very performant I assume. The value range provider needs to return exactly this value by coincidence which will take a lot of time? Taking into account that I have a `CountableValueRange<BigDecimal>` provider.

Comment: Another idea was commented here (https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/discussions/610) by providing a custom range provider together with every entity. However for me at the moment this is not working. The planning variable is always 0.

Comment: Using BigDecimal as a planning value class is strange. Is this using the time grain pattern?

Comment: Hi @GeoffreyDeSmet, no, I'm not using the time grain pattern. The reason is that we have Tasks that can overlap and have influence on a resource over time. So first let the tasks overlap, create distinct intervals, calculate the influence of each task on the resource for the given interval, aggregate them and then go to the previous interval, repeating this. So we construct these intervals in the constraint provider. The reason is that I thought that this is more efficient than having a fixed granularity resulting in a performance degrade and also I cannot plan e.g. second levels.

Comment: Do you think this is a good approach? @GeoffreyDeSmet
Basically I use BigDecimal as a relative second to a specific start. Would it be better to use `LocalDateTime` like you suggest below?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a hard constraint.

In task assignment and vehicle routing, it's common to see minStart and maxStart:

```
class Task {
    LocalDateTime minStart;
    LocalDateTime maxStart;
    
    @PlanningVariable(allowsUnassigned=true)
    LocalDateTime start; // 15 minute granularity (time grain pattern)
}
```

If minStart and maxStart are both non-null and equal, it effectively pins the task to that time, or doesn't assign it all

[image]

Comment: Ah, nice. But then I still need a RangeProvider that is initialized with `minStart` and `maxStart` I guess? Ah sorry, no ofc just using a hard constraint. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't using range providers more efficient because it reduces the search space? The construction heuristic cannot know what actual good values are in order to satisfy the hard constraint and it will take more time to come up with a proper value? Just to understand which approach is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness: The first solution I implemented that actually works is having a different range providers entity and to make the planning variable optional. Then you can also introduce a medium score level to incentivize that those tasks are scheduled at all. Basically combining these two:

- https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/discussions/610
- https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/using-timefold-solver/modeling-planning-problems#nullablePlanningVariable